# How to add a modal window for images on the index page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a partial modal window, which I render to the show page:

```
#myModal.modal.fade
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-body
        %button.close{'aria-hidden' => 'true', 'data-dismiss '=> 'modal', :type => 'button'} ×
        = image_tag(@post.image_url.to_s, class: 'modal-image') if @post
```

show.html.haml:

```
%p#notice= notice

%p
  %b Image:
  = link_to image_tag(@post.image_url(:thumb).to_s), '#', class: 'image'
%p
  %b Title:
  = @post.title
%p
  %b Body:
  = @post.body
%p
  %b User:
  = @post.user_id

= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post)
\|
= link_to 'Back', posts_path
= render 'modal'
```

The code is called through js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.image').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

How do I add a modal window for images on the index page?

index.html.haml:

```
%h1 Галлерея
- @posts.each_slice(3) do |posts_row|
  .row
    -posts_row.each do |post|
      .col-xs-6.col-md-4
        .thumbnail
          = link_to image_tag(post.image_url(:thumb).to_s), '#', class: 'image'
          .caption
            %h3= post.title
            %p= post.body
            %p
              = link_to 'Посмотреть', post
              = link_to 'Редактировать', edit_post_path(post)
              = link_to 'Удалить', post, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path
```